# Remove B and I tagging at NER

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition

I have news articles, I want to do NER using deepavlov to that articles. The entity uses the BIO tagging scheme. Here “B” denotes beginning of an entity, “I” stands for “inside” and is used for all words comprising the entity except the first one, and “O” means the absence of entity. The NER codes are like this:

```
def listOfTuples(list1, list2): 
    return list(map(lambda x, y:(x,y), list1, list2)) 

ner_result = []
for x in split:
    for y in split[0]:
        news_ner = ner_model([str(y)])
        teks =  news_ner[0][0]
        tag = news_ner[1][0]
        ner_result.extend(listOfTuples(teks, tag))

print([i for i in ner_result if i[1] != 'O'])
```

Well, the NER results are like this.

```
[('KOMPAScom', 'B-ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'I-ORG'), ('IFCN', 'B-ORG'), ('-', 'I-ORG'), ('International', 'I-ORG'), ('Fact', 'I-ORG'), ('-', 'I-ORG'), ('Checking', 'I-ORG'), ('Network', 'I-ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'B-ORG'), ('49', 'B-CARDINAL'), ('IFCN', 'B-ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'B-ORG'), ('Redaksi', 'B-ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'I-ORG'), ('Wisnu', 'B-PERSON'), ('Nugroho', 'I-PERSON'), ('Jakarta', 'B-GPE'), ('Rabu', 'B-DATE'), ('17', 'I-DATE'), ('/', 'I-DATE'), ('10', 'I-DATE'), ('/', 'I-DATE'), ('2018', 'I-DATE'), ('KOMPAScom', 'B-ORG'), ('Redaksi', 'B-ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'I-ORG'), ('Wisnu', 'B-PERSON'), ('Nugroho', 'I-PERSON'), ('Kompascom', 'B-ORG'), ('Bentara', 'I-ORG'), ('Budaya', 'I-ORG'), ('Jakarta', 'I-ORG'), ('Palmerah', 'I-ORG')]
```

I want to remove the tags of B and I, then merge the text in tags B and I, so the output goes like this.

```
[('KOMPAScom Kompascom', 'ORG'), ('IFCN - International Fact - Checking Network', 'ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'ORG'), ('49', 'CARDINAL'), ('IFCN', 'ORG'), ('Kompascom', 'ORG'), ('Redaksi Kompascom', 'ORG'), ('Wisnu Nugroho', 'PERSON'), ('Jakarta', 'GPE'), ('Rabu 17/10/2018', 'DATE'), ('KOMPAScom', 'ORG'), ('Redaksi Kompascom', 'ORG'), ('Wisnu Nugroho', 'PERSON'), ('Kompascom Bentara Budaya Jakarta Palmerah', 'ORG')]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply iterate over the tagged text and join tokens belonging to the same entity. It is not amazingly elegant, but it works. Something like this:

```py
def collapse(ner_result):
    # List with the result
    collapsed_result = []

    # Buffer for tokens belonging to the most recent entity
    current_entity_tokens = []
    current_entity = None

    # Iterate over the tagged tokens
    for token, tag in ner_result:
        if tag == "O":
            continue
        # If an enitity span starts ...
        if tag.startswith("B-"):
            # ... if we have a previous entity in the buffer, store it in the result list
            if current_entity is not None:
                collapsed_result.append(
                    (" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity))

            current_entity = tag[2:]
            # The new entity has so far only one token
            current_entity_tokens = [token]
        # If the entity continues ...
        elif tag == "I-" + current_entity:
            # Just add the token buffer
            current_entity_tokens.append(token)
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid tag order.")

    # The last entity is still in the buffer, so add it to the result
    # ... but only if there were some entity at all
    if current_entity is not None:
        collapsed_result.append(
            (" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity))
    return collapsed_result
```

Comment: `   if current_entity is not None:
        collapsed_result.append(
            (" ".join(current_entity_tokens), current_entity))
    return collapsed_result`
would you like to explain about that codes?

Comment: It remembers tokens belonging to the entities the `current_entity_tokens` list. In the loop over the entity tokens, this list gets processed (i.e., put spaces between tokens and store in a list that return by the function) when a new entity starts. This means that the last entity is not added in the list and must be added after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

A small change to the above code to get start index, end index and average score.

Input:

```
[['JP', 'B-ORG', 16, 18, 0.9992533922195435],
 ['Morgan', 'I-ORG', 19, 25, 0.9974533319473267],
 ['Data', 'B-ORG', 27, 31, 0.9988869428634644],
 ['##bri', 'I-ORG', 31, 34, 0.9955556988716125],
 ['##cks', 'I-ORG', 34, 37, 0.9981479048728943],
 ['American', 'B-ORG', 42, 50, 0.9994726777076721],
 ['Express', 'I-ORG', 51, 58, 0.9991927742958069]]
```

Output:

```
[('JP Morgan', 'ORG', 16, 25, 0.9983533620834351),
 ('Databricks', 'ORG', 27, 37, 0.9975301822026571),
 ('American Express', 'ORG', 42, 58, 0.9993327260017395)]
```

```
def collapse(ner_result):
    # List with the result
    collapsed_result = []

    # Buffer for tokens belonging to the most recent entity
    current_entity_tokens = []
    current_entity = None
    
    current_start = None
    current_end = None
    current_score = 0.0

    # Iterate over the tagged tokens
    for token, tag, st, en, scre in ner_result:
        if tag == "O":
            continue
        # If an enitity span starts ...
        if tag.startswith("B-"):
            # ... if we have a previous entity in the buffer, store it in the result list
            if current_entity is not None:
                collapsed_result.append(
                    (" ".join(current_entity_tokens).replace(' ##', ''), current_entity, current_start, current_end, current_score/len(current_entity_tokens)))

            current_entity = tag[2:]
            current_start = st
            current_end = en
            current_score = scre
            # The new entity has so far only one token
            current_entity_tokens = [token]
        # If the entity continues ...
        elif tag == "I-" + current_entity:
            # Just add the token buffer
            current_entity_tokens.append(token)
            current_end = en
            current_score+= scre
        else:
            raise ValueError("Invalid tag order.")

    # The last entity is still in the buffer, so add it to the result
    # ... but only if there were some entity at all
    if current_entity is not None:
        collapsed_result.append(
            (" ".join(current_entity_tokens).replace(' ##', ''), current_entity, current_start, current_end, current_score/len(current_entity_tokens)))
    return collapsed_result
```